# How can I make an engine by using adiabatic expansion?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work, adiabatic

In adiabatic expansion, gases expand when heating so volume and pressure also increase. How can I convert into work?

Answer (score 1):

An adiabatic process is defined as one in which no heat is exchanged between the system and its surroundings. Consequently, the first law of thermodynamics tells us that the variation in the internal energy corresponds only to work.